# postgres - select the "highest scored" column_name from left to right

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, greatest-n-per-group

(please be patient with a self-taught but fascinated beginner in postgres :)

In POSTGRES 10 I have come up with a table to track the progress in editing and archiving photo folders. This progress is measured in sequential steps, which link via foreign_key to another table that basically states 0 = "open", 1 = "work", 2 = "done". Hence I use numeric values to reference these states.

To keep the question simple here are the **most important columns with some demo data**:

```
folder_name  |  archive_status  |  step_01  |  step_02  |  step_03  |  ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
john         |         *        |     0     |     2     |     0     |  ...
paul         |         *        |     0     |     0     |     2     |  ...
george       |         *        |     2     |     1     |     0     |  ...
ringo        |         *        |     0     |     2     |     0     |  ...
```

The **desired result** would be something like:

```
folder_name  |  archive_status  |  step_01  |  step_02  |  step_03  |  ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
john         |     step_02      |     0     |     2     |     0     |  ...
paul         |     step_03      |     0     |     0     |     2     |  ...
george       |     step_01      |     2     |     1     |     0     |  ...
ringo        |     step_02      |     0     |     2     |     0     |  ...
```

**My two problems are:**

1. Considering my "steps" sequentially I would like to filter the "highest" ranked one (from left to right). So in the example above "john" has reached step_02", "paul has reached step_03" and so on. (Note that other values such as "george ... step_02 = 1" are irrelevant for this.)
2. Can't wrap my head around the way to accomplish this within the same table upon update on any of the values - would I have to use FUNCTION or VIEW or TRIGGER (or a combination of them)?

I tried approaching it with the Aggregate Functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/tutorial-agg.html but I am kind of stuck, since I don't need multiple input rows, but filtering multiple columns within a row.

**--- UPDATE: New problem ---**

Sorry for that, but my **initial demo data was not clear enough**, these columns act more as a progress tracker, where in fact EACH cell within these columns could show any value. (This is where the original solution in the answer fails, since if there are two same "highest" values in a row, it will use the first occurence.) So the SQL query should find the column at the farthest to the right so to speak. Of cource I could come up with some clever "score calculations" over here, but in fact things would be so much easier with this current "matrix style" design.

So again, the **desired result** (archive_status) according to the values (step_xx) would be:

```
folder_name  |  archive_status  |  step_01  |  step_02  |  step_03 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
john         |     step_02      |     2     |     2     |     0    
paul         |     step_03      |     1     |     1     |     2   
george       |     step_01      |     2     |     1     |     1   
ringo        |     step_02      |     2     |     2     |     1
```

Comment: A better data model would store the statuses in separate rows rather than separate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses `greatest()` and a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
    case greatest(step_01, step_02, step_03)
        when step_01 then 'step_01'
        when step_02 then 'step_02'
        when step_03 then 'step_03'
    end as archive_status
from mytable t
```

While this would work for your current problem, I would recommend normalizing your design. Each step should be stored in a separate *row* rather than as a column, in a structure like `(folder_name, step, status)`.  Then you would use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (folder_name) t.*
from newtable t
order by folder_name, status desc, step
```

Comment: That's definitely of great help. Thank you very much. Will also consider the advice to normalize my design. – Though I just found out that my **demo data was not clear enough**. I think more of a progress bar here ... see below.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to GMB's helpful answer above one minor change did the trick for my updated problem. This was to find out about the column "farthest to the right" in the sequence. Since the execution of CASE ... WHEN stops as soon as the first condition is met sucessfully ("true"), the trick was just to change the order of the WHEN statements. So the following code worked for me:

```
   select t.*,
    case greatest(step_01, step_02, step_03)
        when step_03 then 'step_03'
        when step_02 then 'step_02'
        when step_01 then 'step_01'
        else 'step_00'
    end as archive_status
from mytable t
```